# When using vue-virtual-scroller where does content-tag and main-tag come from

Tags: javascript, vue.js, virtualscroll

I am trying to understand the vue virtual scroller. I noticed in the demo there are a couple HTML attributes it uses...

`<virtual-scroller v-if="scopedSlots" class="scroller" :item-height="itemHeight" :items="items" main-tag="section" content-tag="table" :buffer="buffer" :pool-size="poolSize">`

[link to the specific line on source code](https://github.com/Akryum/vue-virtual-scroller/blob/master/docs-src/src/App.vue#L27)

Where does this ability come from and where is the documentation for it?

Answer (score 0):

Breakdown:

- `v-if` - [vue directive](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/conditional.html)
- `class` - normal html attribute that you probably already know.
- `item-height`- [computed Method](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html).
- `items` - [data object property](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/#Declarative-Rendering).
- `buffer` - [data object property](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/#Declarative-Rendering)
- `pool-size` - [data object property](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/#Declarative-Rendering)

please notice that `item-height` for example is written as `kebab-case` on the html side, but should be written with camelCase on the javascript side. like so: `itemHeight`

about the `content-tag`, `main-tag` - worth a shot to ask the developer on github. those are not part of official vue api, nor part of html spec.

Comment: I got all those I was trying to figure out where those properties came from. Was it that project or another one.

Comment: what? didnt understand u

Comment: How do I find where these are declared. Assuming they are declared in this project.

Comment: Read the answer. The data object properties are declared. In they are written in camel-case. Pool-size is poolSize.

Answer (score 0):

These are props declared in ../src/components/VirtualScroller.vue.

Both "content-tag" and "main-tag" are props of type String, meaning you can pass your choice of html elements. In your copied example, "section" and "table" is being passed to each prop, which is simply a string. If no value is passed, it would default to "div", which was set here: https://github.com/Akryum/vue-virtual-scroller/blob/master/src/components/VirtualScroller.vue

The string can also be passed dynamically, as they do for :item-height="itemHeight", where you would have :main-tag="mainTag" or :main-tag="anyCustomMainTag". This would allow you to set mainTag or anyCustomMainTag to your string value, which would also override the default div.